# What is the reverse for Update-Database (used in Package Manager Console)?

Tags: entity-framework, nuget, nuget-package

I have been changing my domain classes and executed Update-Database in the Package Manager Console, After i realized that need to add an index and need to down-grade to the previous state. what is the proper command to down-grade one step in migration?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Update-Database has a TargetMigration parameter that you can use to update to a particular migration. You can use that to upgrade or downgrade.

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration PreviousMigrationName
```

Comment: What if this is the first migration which I have applied on my database. How revert these changes?

Answer (score 6):

For **Entity Framework Core ONLY**
and if you are using it from Package Manager

```
Update-Database –Migration yourMigrationName
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration "lastcreatedMigrationName"
```

example:

```
update-database -targetmigration: "entity-logs-index"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rollback all migrations you can use (Stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282532/entity-framework-start-over-undo-rollback-all-migrations)):

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:0
```

But in EF Core it is

```
Update-Database -Migration:0
```

Answer (score 0):

To continue this, if you have outstanding model changes i do believe this will fail.  This can be frustrating when you already have code in place.

`Update-Database –TargetMigration "targetmigrationname" -force`

If you use this command and include the `force` flag the database will migrate to that version regardless of having outstanding model changes.